# How to set attributes on Application Context through a Jetty server Handler

Tags: java, jetty, restlet

I set up a Jetty server and bind it to a Restlet Application :

```
                    server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(PORT);

                    final ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
                    servletContext.setContextPath("/");
                    servletContext.setInitParameter("org.restlet.application", MyApplication.class.getName());
                    servletContext.addServlet(ServerServlet.class, "/*");
                    servletContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

                    server.setHandler(servletContext);
                    server.start();
                    server.join();
```

However I want to set some attribute to the Application context. How to manage that. I tried this but it does not do the trick, and I fear I am awfully misundertanding how the Restlet Context is handled is such case...

```
    servletContext.setAttribute("agent", this);
```

It keeps giving an empty Context in MyApplication(Context parentContext) call...

I am lost there. How can I give software context to my Restlet Application in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look into the source code (see https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.ext.servlet/src/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.java#L947), it appears that both init parameters from servlet config and servlet context are copied in the Restlet application context within its `parameters` list.

So you can pass parameters from servlet context to the Restlet application context. Here is a sample:

- Defining the parameter when configuring the servlet context

  ```
  final ServletContextHandler servletContext
     = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
  servletContext.setContextPath("/");

  servletContext.setInitParameter(
    "org.restlet.application", MyApplication.class.getName());
  servletContext.setInitParameter("test", "my param"); <-----------

  servletContext.addServlet(ServerServlet.class, "/*");
  servletContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
  ```
- Getting the parameter within the Restlet application class

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
      public MyApplication () {
          super();
      }

      @Override
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Series<Parameter> parameters = getContext().getParameters();
          for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
              System.out.println("- parameter = "+parameter);
          }

          (...)
      }
  }
  ```

There is also another (but intrusive) approach since Restlet keeps an instance on the ServletContext within the application context. This allows to pass objects not only string ones. Here is a sample:

- Defining the parameter when configuring the servlet context

  ```
  final ServletContextHandler servletContext
    = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
  servletContext.setContextPath("/");

  servletContext.setAttribute("myAttr", new ArrayList<>());

  servletContext.addServlet(ServerServlet.class, "/*");
  servletContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
  ```
- Getting the parameter within the Restlet application class

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
      public MyApplication () {
          super();
      }

      @Override
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          ServletContext context
            = (ServletContext) getContext().getAttributes().get(
                    "org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletContext");
          List l = (List) context.getAttribute("myAttr");
          (...)
      }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks once more Thierry :)
Actually I should have been more specific : my need is to add some object to the context, not only a string value. As in the checked answer in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073686/restlet-server-resource-with-constructor-parameters-needed
router.getContext().getAttributes().put(CONNECTION_POOL_KEY, connectionPool);

Comment: You're welcome! There is a way to do that but it depends on the `ServletContext` class itself... I updated my answer to show you it. Hope it will answer your issue!